# NSPredicate for filtering array of primitives field in Realm 3

Tags: swift, realm, nspredicate

We have to store elements in Realm that have array of string field.

To do this we have to implement small workaround:

```
class RealmString: Object {
    @objc dynamic var value = ""
    override init(value: Any) {
        super.init(value: [value])
    }
    required init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) {
        super.init(realm: realm, schema: schema)
    }
    required init() {
        super.init()
    }
    required init(value: Any, schema: RLMSchema) {
        super.init(value: [value], schema: schema)
    }
}

class Realm2Element: Object {
    let tags = List<RealmString>()
}
```

As a result:

1. **CONTAINS ALL OF** condition looks like this:

`ANY tags.value == "tag0" AND ANY tags.value == "tag1" AND ANY tags.value == "tag2"`

2. **CONTAINS ANY OF** condition looks like this:

`ANY tags.value IN {"tag0", "tag1", "tag2"}`

Realm3 suppors array of primitives. We removed `.value` keyPath from condition. But we have got error when applied these filters for `Realm3Element`:

```
class Realm3Element: Object {
    let tags = List<String>()
}
```

For **CONTAINS ALL OF** condition:

```
'Invalid value', reason: 'Expected object of type (null) for property 'tags' on object of type 'Realm3Element', but received: tag0'
```

For **CONTAINS ANY OF** condition:

```
'Expected object of type (null) in IN clause for property 'tags' on object of type 'Realm3Element', but received: tag0'
```

We run through the all possible variations, but couldn't find any solution.

Does Realm3 support filtering by array of primitives field?

Comment: `Does Realm3 support filtering by array of primitives field?` not yet, and I was hoping it'd be in like sometime 3 months ago, but I see zero progress in this regard unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve your goals using `predicate` with Realm because Realm have a lot of limitations using `Predicates`  but you can use this way as a workaround

```
  let filterArray = ["tag0","tag1"]
    Array(realm.objects(Realm3Element.self)).filter({$0.tags.sorted().joined().contains(filterArray.sorted().joined())})
```

If you want a perfect solution tracking this issue [#5334](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5334)

Comment: This method is very slow

Comment: how much number of element in your array ?

Comment: About a thouthands elements of Realm2Element,
and About a dozen elements of RealmString for each Realm2Element

Comment: Ok , Wait i'm check this case

Comment: @AlexBishop I'm trying this code number of item `2203` it's working smoothly